# How to insert only new key to existing key:value pair dictionary python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dict as below:

```
dict1={
       'item1': 
         {'result': 
           [{'val': 228, 'no': 202}]
         }, 
       'item2': 
         {'result':   
           [{'value': 148, 'year': 201}]
         } 
      }
```

How can we insert a new key 'category' to each item so that the output looks like below:

```
output={
       'item1': 
        {'category': 
          {'result': 
           [{'val': 228, 'no': 202}]
          }
        }, 
       'item2': 
       {'category':  
         {'result': 
           [{'value': 148, 'year': 201}]
         }
       }
       }
```

Currently, i have key:value and im looking to insert newkey which takes same value, key:newkey:value

I tried to do `dict1['item1']['category1']` but this is adding a new key value pair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use to modify in-place the existing dictionary `dict1`:

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
    dict1[key] = { "category" : value }

print(dict1)
```

**Output**

```
{'item1': {'category': {'result': [{'val': 228, 'no': 202}]}}, 'item2': {'category': {'result': [{'value': 148, 'year': 201}]}}}
```

As an alternative use [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
dict1.update((k, {"category": v}) for k, v in dict1.items())
```

Note that `update` receives both a dictionary or an iterable of key/value pairs, from the documentation:

> update() accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of
> key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two).

Finally in Python 3.9+, you can use the merge operator (`|=`), as below:

```
dict1 |= ((k, {"category": v}) for k, v in dict1.items())
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
out = {k: {"category": v} for k, v in dict1.items()}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "item1": {"category": {"result": [{"val": 228, "no": 202}]}},
    "item2": {"category": {"result": [{"value": 148, "year": 201}]}},
}
```

Comment: would have been funny if it would be _Try: ... Finally:_ instead of _Print:_ lol